# Как приявзять удаленный git репозиторий с Windows 10 машины через ssh

Tags: git

На Windows 10 я установил ssh сервер и настроил ключи и с компа на linuxe я могу подключиться так ssh -l Viacheslav 192.168.1.7 - то есть соединение по ssh работает и я могу подключиться к консоли винды.

Репозиторий находится в папке `C:\Project-api\.git`

Я попытался привязать так

`git remote set-url origin Viacheslav@192.168.1.7:22C:\\Project-api\\.git`

Но возникает ошибка Could not read from remote repository

`git remote -v` дает

```
origin  Viacheslav@192.168.1.7:22C:\Project-api\.git (fetch)
origin  Viacheslav@192.168.1.7:22C:\Project-api\.git (push)
```

Как правильно привязать такой репозиторий?

Comment: 22 это что такое?

Comment: Viacheslav@192.168.1.7:C:\\Project-api

Comment: url должен быть вида `192.168.1.7:22C:/Project-api.git` И убедитесь, что там bare репозиторий.